# title bar went missing after using oncreateoptionsmenu in android studio

Tags: android

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    }

    @Override //my code for action bar but it makes the action bar missing
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly returning true?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```